# @layout/layoutID Error on XML

Tags: android, xml

im trying to run a sample code but i get this error when i run the application i get the error on xmp preview and run time

```
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543): Process: net.micode.compass, PID: 1543
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.miui.compass/net.miui.compass.CompassActivity}: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-23 22:04:02.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1543):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
```

and here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_compass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/prompt" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_direction"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                    </ImageView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_angle"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/background_compass" />

                    <net.micode.compass.CompassView
                        android:id="@+id/compass_pointer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/compass" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/miui_cover" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/location_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/getting_location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#7FFFFFFF" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<include

    android:id="@+id/low_accuracy_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

i know i should add layout but where ?
even xml preview is not working . and the full error is this : Exception raised during rendering: You must specifiy a layout in the include tag:

Comment: Have you defined `low_accuracy_view.xml` layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example XML has an <include> element which is missing a layout attribute. The layout attribute should be specified as a layout resource. You also seem to be missing the closing </FrameLayout> tag.

```
    ...
    <include
        layout="@layout/my_layout"
        ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

For some layout XML file res/layout/my_layout.xml.

Comment: layout="@layout/main" added this and says layout main cant include itself framelayout is ok i add the  </FrameLayout> tag

Comment: And what is the name of the layout where you're adding the <include> tag?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file provided, the `include` tag has not `android:layout` perporty that is **required**. [Learn more details...](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)